# How to place the logo on top and footer on bottom?

Tags: html, css, styled-components

I need the logo block to always be on top of the page and the footer to be on the bottom of the page, regardless of the extension.
And block width inputs must be in middle of page.
now i have that

[image]

I`m use styled components

Logo.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components'


export default styled.div`
    padding-top: 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    align-self: flex-start;
`
```

FooterMain.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components'


export default styled.div`
    width: 440px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 55px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;

`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `position:absolute` and then set `top:0` for header and `bottom:0` for footer. Hope this helps.

```css
#header, #container, #footer { 
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  background: #3980dd
 }

#header{
   height:20px; top:0;
}

#footer{
  height:20px; bottom:0;
}

#container{
  top:20px;
  bottom:20px;
  background: #a03347;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="container">This is my container</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```